# Who do I need to grant permissions to in my db if my Windows service is running under ServiceAccount.LocalService?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, windows-services

I have a database `MyDb` which my Windows service whose account is  `ServiceAccount.LocalService` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.serviceaccount(v=vs.110).aspx) and am getting an error when I run the service that the service doesn't have permissions to execute against the db. I know I probably need to run a `GRANT EXECUTE TO ...` but I'm wondering to whom. Also my connection string in my app is

```
 <add name="LocalDb" connectionString="Data Source=DESKTOP-300NQR3\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MyDb;Integrated Security=True" />
```

and I'm wondering what that needs to be

Comment: I don't think `LocalService` can sign in to a service on another machine. You will probably need SQL server authentication instead of Windows authentication/Integrated security.

Comment: Understand that if there are 10 machines on a network, there are 10 `LocalService` accounts. How do you expect a MS SQL DB instance to know their differences? You should use a (non in-built) User on that workgroup or domain

Answer (score 0):

Try setting up Username and Password for your connection string.

```
<add name="DatabaseLinkage" connectionString="Data source=<HOSTNAME>;Initial Catalog=<DB_NAME>;Integrated Security=False;user id=<DB_USERNAME>;password=<DB_PASSWORD>" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: How do I create such a user? Under `MyDb > Security > Users`? When I do `New User` there's a `User Name` and `Login Name` field, but no password field.

Comment: Do not choose your Database name and then Security. Choose Security directly, then `right click on Logins` and click on `New Login`. Choose `SQL Server authentication`, then fill your username at the top, passwords and the relevant database at the bottom.